# Using a variable name in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, xml, xmlhttprequest

I am using jQuery and trying to load a variable in place of a named xml file. 
My Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        // bind 'myForm' and provide a simple callback function 
        $('#theForm').ajaxForm(function(responseXML2) { 

            var myxml = responseXML2;
            alert(responseXML2);
            displayResult();


           }); 
}); 
function loadXMLDoc(dname)
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  alert("loading xmlhttprequest");
  xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  alert("loading activeX");
  xhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
alert("bottom load");
xhttp.open("GET",dname,false);
xhttp.send();
return xhttp.responseXML;
}

function displayResult()
{
alert("setting vars");

alert("displayResult called");

//xml=loadXMLDoc(responseXML2);  //tried this and the line below, among others
xml=responseXML2;
alert("xmlDocLoaded");
xsl=loadXMLDoc("xslt-test.xsl");
alert("XSLloaded");
// code for IE
if (window.ActiveXObject)
  {
  alert("IE");
  ex=xml.transformNode(xsl);
  document.getElementById("ieiresponse").innerHTML=ex;
  }
// code for Mozilla, Firefox, Opera, etc.
else if (document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument)
  {
  alert("notIE");
  xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
  xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(xsl);
  resultDocument = xsltProcessor.transformToFragment(xml,document);
  document.getElementById("ieiresponse").appendChild(resultDocument);
  }
}
```

In the code above I want to have:

```
//xml=loadXMLDoc(responseXML2);  //tried this and the line below, among others
xml=responseXML2;
```

instead of a named file:

```
xsl=loadXMLDoc("example.xml");
```

When I run through the code, it works if I name the file, but when I use the variable, (which does show up in alerts, so is being pulled), it stops the code at the above line (placing the variable as the xml file)

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Comment: You have jQuery and do things like `if (window.XMLHttpRequest)`? Why?!

Comment: I'm using jQuery to retrieve the XML response of a form post. If there is a better way (I am new to XML) I am very much open to it!

Comment: I am looking more through the code, and it looks like responseXML2 isn't being pulled into the new function. I have tried placing the existing displayresult() code on the bottom under here:
     $('#theForm').ajaxForm(function(responseXML2) { 

            var myxml = responseXML2;
            alert(responseXML2);
            Placing code here

With no luck, now it's not even calling the alerts!

Comment: But jQuery has all those nice functions built in, why don't you use them? You do not seem to have read the most basic things about jQuery and the extension you use (the jquery form plugin, I presume), but instead started to write dozens of lines of code already. That's certainly the wrong approach.

Comment: I have been reading for the last 3 days! This is all very new to me, but if you can point me in the right direction/function to look at I will. I have tried the other jquery plugins like jquery.xslt.js, etc.

See my other post when I was just straight using jquery - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846447/cannot-get-xml-to-transform-with-xslt

Comment: It will be best if you describe, in English, what you have and what you want. I'm not sure if I understand from your code.

Comment: working almost now, but having problem with this line: document.getElementById("ieiresponse").appendChild(resultDocument);
I nested the function inside the other and was able to access responseXML2 but working on getting it visible on the div now

Comment: I essentially want to post a form to a server, receive the response back in XML, apply an XSLT to the XML and display it in a div on the page. Thanks for your patience Tomalek, I am still learning so much!

Comment: looks like with a few more alerts to see what is going on, xml is coming back null..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments:

> I essentially want to post a form to a server, 
>   receive the response back in XML, apply an XSLT 
>   to the XML and display it in a div on the page.

From what I can see, something like this should already do everything you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // prepare sending the AJAX form (use ajaxSubmit() to actually send it)
  $('#theForm').ajaxForm({
    dataType: 'xml', 
    success:  function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
      // jQuery xslt plugin required for this:
      $.xslt({
        xml: xhr.responseXML,
        xslUrl: "xslt-test.xsl",
        target: "#ieiresponse"
      });
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      alert("Oops, there was an error: " + textStatus);
    }
  });
});
```

Your code is incredibly riddled with things that jQuery already does for you (like choosing the right XmlHttpRequest object depending on the browser type, and other stuff). You can and should get rid of all of this. And you should begin reading some jQuery tutorials, because even though you say differently, your code does not indicate *at all* that you really have.

Comment: Hi Tomalek.
Thank you very much for the code. I am trying this, but when I click the form submit button, nothing happens. I was having this problem with xslt earlier. Perhaps it is something I did wrong in referencing the xslt.js?

Comment: Here is my code for referencing the js:
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/xslt.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/jquery.xslt.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/jquery-1.4.2.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.mydomain.com/jquery.form.js"></script>

Comment: With me just trying the xslt.js and jquery.xslt.js both being in there. Usually it is just one.

Comment: @Paul: *Do* you use `ajaxSubmit()`, like my comment says? P.S.: I have no idea what may be wrong with your referenced script files, and (in all honesty) you should be able to sort that out yourself.

Comment: thanks Tomalek, no I wasn't using ajaxSubmit. Let me play around with that and see how it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I answered my own question:
Here is the result for others

1) I nested my function so it could actually reference the variable.
2) I replaced

```
xml=loadXMLDoc(responseXML2);
```

with:

```
xml=responseXML2;
```

which now worked inside the nested function.